# Iron router issue in meteor application

Tags: iron-router, meteorite

I am doing my first Meteor application and facing some issues in navigation using the iron router. Everytime, I click the Signin button from the signing template, it doesn't redirect me to home page template. The browser shows a url with a question mark in it after signing button is clicked(`http://localhost:3000/?`). The weird thing is that after I click the back button in browser, it takes me to home page with URL:`http://localhost:3000/home`. I am not able to understand why this is happening. Please help me to find what I am doing wrong.

In the router.js file, I have written:

```
Router.configure({

  layoutTemplate: 'layout',


});



Router.map(function() {


  this.route('/home',function()
  {
        this.render('home');
  });
  this.route('/',function()
  {
        this.render('signin');
  });

});
```

The layout file looks like this:

```
<template name="layout">

    <div>
        {{>header}}
    </div>


    <div>
        {{>yield}}
    </div>

    <div>
        {{>footer}}
    </div>

</template>
```

SignIn template file looks like this:

```
<template name="signin">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

            <div class="account-wall">
                <h1 class="text-center login-title">Sign in to continue</h1>
                <form class="form-signin">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                    Sign in</button>
                <label class="checkbox pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                    Remember me
                </label>
                <a href="#" class="pull-right need-help">Need help? </a><span class="clearfix"></span>
                </form>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="text-center new-account">Create an account </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</template>
```

Home template looks like:

```
<template name="home">    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3>Column 1</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3>Column 2</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3>Column 3</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>
```

The code for Signin.js file is as follow:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) 
{


    console.log("Sign In JS");

    Template.signin.helpers({

    });

    Template.signin.events({

        'submit': function(event, template) {
           // alert("My button was clicked!");
            Router.go('home');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I your case you have to use the [path](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#using-javascript)
`Router.go("/home")`